# Sql Serverless database (Azure Synapse Analytics): You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement

Tags: sql-server, azure-functions, serverless, azure-synapse, azure-managed-identity

I'm getting getting a "You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement" in a Sql Serverless database (Azure Synapse Analytics).

I tried various methods to no avail:

```
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'%username%', @rolename = N'bulkadmin'
```

from: [You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002529/you-do-not-have-permission-to-use-the-bulk-load-statement/73553783#73553783)

and

```
GRANT ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS TO username
```

from: [SQL Server - You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55284100/sql-server-you-do-not-have-permission-to-use-the-bulk-load-statement)

None of these seem to work in the Sql Serverless context

I ended up just using a db_owner and db_denydatawriter combo like this:

```
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [username]; -- owner allows bulk operations
ALTER ROLE db_denydatawriter ADD MEMBER [username]; -- deny writer in our specific case
```

This works, but it just doesn't feel right to make this particular user db_owner. Does anybody know of a better way to do this?

I'm trying to do a simple `SELECT` on a `VIEW` referencing a delta table (haven't tried it for parquet, but I'm expecting the same). I'm guessing SQL Serverless uses bulk load for this operation.

I'm doing this using `System.Data.SqlClient` (v5.x) from a Function App, with a Managed Identity. I don't think that matters much, as it's really a SQL roles issue.

**##EDIT##**
The proposed solutions are pretty much the same. I tried this but it doesn't seem to work.
As mentioned before, I'm using a Managed Identity to connect to the database, maybe that's the cause of the current issue.

The SQL statements to grant the permissions work fine, and the user seems to have all the correct permissions when I query the sys tables. However, when executing from the Function App I now receive the following Exception:

> Cannot find the CREDENTIAL 'datahub_api', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
> Could not use view or function 'HR.Employee' because of binding errors."

This credential does exist however.
Adding my user to db_owner makes the Exception go away.

I'm using the following to create the credential:

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [datahub_api] WITH IDENTITY='Managed Identity'

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE "datalakehouse" WITH (

    LOCATION = '<url to datalakehouse storage>',

    CREDENTIAL = datahub_api

);
```

The user is created like this:

```
CREATE USER [username] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

**##EDIT##**
Also worth mentioning is that I tried granting alter on the `[HR]` schema as well. Don't think this is necessary though, because I think this permission is only needed for some behind the scenes temp tables when doing the bulk load. Not sure about this so don't quote me on it :-)

Comment: Those answers are for SQL Server on Premises (and `sp_addsrvrolemember` has been long deprecated now too). Perhaps this is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/quickstart-bulk-load-copy-tsql#set-up-the-required-permissions) you are after?

Comment: The docs you referenced apply to dedicated SQL pools, not serverless SQL. They rely on GRANT ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS, which doesn't seem to work in this context

Comment: `GRANT ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS` <> `GRANT ADMINISTER DATABASE BULK OPERATIONS TO`

Comment: fair point, i'll give it a go :-)

Comment: Thank you for the input. Still not working though. See ##EDIT##

Comment: What statement are you running when you get the error? I hope you know Synapse Serverless doesn’t allow you to create tables and store rows in them. It just supports views and external tables which query over files in storage. Or you can write files to storage with CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT.

Comment: I am well aware of that.
We were able to fix the issue, see my own answer to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had a little chat with one of our data engineers and we found the solution I was looking for.

So first we create the `CREDENTIAL` and `USER` as mentioned before:

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [datahub_api] WITH IDENTITY='Managed Identity'

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE "datalakehouse" WITH (

    LOCATION = '<url to datalakehouse storage>',

    CREDENTIAL = datahub_api

);

CREATE USER [username] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
/*
username is the same as the function app name in our case; 
this is the name of the managed identity created by azure when creating a System Assigned Managed Identity
*/
```

Next we grant the following permissions:

```
GRANT SELECT TO [username] ;

GRANT CONTROL ON DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL :: [datahub_api] to [username];

GRANT ADMINISTER DATABASE BULK OPERATIONS TO [username];
```

And then we threw in a denywriter, just for good measure:

```
ALTER ROLE db_denydatawriter ADD MEMBER [username];
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried what I given here in Microsoft official document [Bulk load data using the COPY statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/quickstart-bulk-load-copy-tsql#set-up-the-required-permissions) and it is working fine for me by using below code.

1. Firstly I have created a new user in the database.

```
CREATE LOGIN utkarsh2 WITH PASSWORD = 'Utrolic123';
GO
CREATE USER utkarsh2 FROM LOGIN utkarsh2;
GO
```

[image]

2. List the permissions for your user in your Serverless database

```
select  princ.name
,       princ.type_desc
,       perm.permission_name
,       perm.state_desc
,       perm.class_desc
,       object_name(perm.major_id)
from    sys.database_principals princ
left join
        sys.database_permissions perm
on      perm.grantee_principal_id = princ.principal_id
where name = 'utkarsh2';
```

[image]

3. Make sure your user has the permissions to CREATE tables in the [dbo] schema

```
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO utkarsh2;
GO
GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::dbo TO utkarsh2;
GO
```

[image]

4. Now you can give the `ADMINISTER DATABASE BULK OPERATIONS` permissions to the user

```
GRANT ADMINISTER DATABASE BULK OPERATIONS TO utkarsh2;
```

[image]

Please follow the same and you will be able to bulk insert after this permission.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Still not working though. See ##EDIT##